# Approval Questions

Tags: approval-process

I am in the process of creating approval process (workflow and approvals). I have a multiple approvers. Here are the approval steps:

1. The creator submits the first part of the record to the first approver
2. The first approver additionally adds additional information to the record and sends the second approver
3. Second approver approves and forward for the next approver the approval
4. The third approver approves. End

My questions are:

- How do I enable the second approver to see more fields and enter data ?
- Can I add a url link in the confirmation email. I don not know if I can edit fields from email?
- Can I have two types of emails: one for approval and only one for notification?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I enable the second approver to see more fields and enter data ?

Create a separate recordtype and page layout and update the recordtype by workflow field update from first approval action.

> Can I add a url link in the confirmation email. I don not know if I can edit fields from email?

Yes, you can create Email template providing URL. Better to open salesforce clicking on the click and update the data.

> Can I have two types of emails: one for approval and only one for notification?

Yes, you can have separate email templates.

Comment: is that my answer serves your purpose?